# uWSGI / Flask / Python logs stop after some time

Tags: python, logging, flask, uwsgi

I have a uWSGI / Flask setup using python loggers. Though logs only from some workers get to the logs and after some time even those cease to show up at all. My hypothesis is that when uWSGI restarts (clones) workers, logging somehow gets broken. Any ideas?

`app/server.py`:

```
app = Flask(...)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
app.logger.addHandler(handler)
app.run()
```

uWSGI:

```
uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/*.ini --die-on-term --uid www-data --gid www-data --logto /var/www/app.com/logs/uwsgi/emperor.log --socket /tmp/uwsgi/emperor.sock --enable-threads --master --single-interpreter --log-reopen --chmod-socket=770
```

apps-enabled/app-0.ini and apps-enabled/app-1.ini look like this:

```
module=server:app
enable-threads=true
single-interpreter=true
master=true
chdir=/var/www/app.com/app
env=APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT=production
venv=/var/www/app.com/virtualenv

logto=/var/www/app.com/logs/uwsgi/app.com-0.log
log-reopen=true
chmod-socket=770
buffer-size=65535

lazy-apps=true
max-requests=5000
heartbeat=15

for=0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
socket=/tmp/uwsgi/app.0.%(_).sock
endfor=

processes=8

map-socket=0:1
map-socket=1:2
map-socket=2:3
map-socket=3:4
map-socket=4:5
map=socket=5:6
map=socket=6:7
map=socket=7:8
```

I have also tried to use `SysLogHandler` with the same result.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. After a while nothing gets logged. I'm using flask / uwsgi / nginx.

Comment: hi, so did you manage to solve this problem? ran into the same issue, since yesterday, and getting nowhere!

Comment: @bool.dev, I still haven't found a solution. Finally reverted back to default uwsgi logging.

Comment: cool, can you tell me what exactly do you mean by default uwsgi logging?

Comment: I'm using `TimedRotatingFileHandler` and it works absolutely fine. may I could help you if you give more details

Comment: What are the privileges that the log files are being created as? Is it possible that the log files are created as root, but reopened as a normal user?

Comment: I notice that you had the `logto` option both in the config file and on the command line pointing to two different log files. I don't know if that has anything to do with this, but I just thought I'd point that out.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that this will help in your case, but you can try to use post forking in uWSGI.

The `postfork` decorator is just the ticket. You can declare multiple postfork tasks. Each decorated function will be executed in sequence after each `fork()`.

```
@postfork
def init_logging():
    app.logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Or you can specify `lazy-apps=true` in your `uwsgi.ini`.

For details: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PythonDecorators.html and http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/articles/TheArtOfGracefulReloading.html

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you for sure is that restarting uwsgi should not stop logging. I have nginx-uwsgi-django server and I restart my uwsgi server all the time and my logs never stop. Here is what my ini file looks like: may be you can tweak your ini file as per this and see if it works.

```
1 #mysite_uwsgi.ini
2 [uwsgi]
3 
4 # Django-related settings
5 # the base directory (full path)
6 chdir           = /home/user/bdapps_stage
7 # Django's wsgi file
8 module          = mysite.wsgi:application
9 # the virtualenv (full path)
10 home            = /home/user/.conda/envs/mysite_env/
11 
12 # process-related settings
13 # master
14 master          = true
15 # maximum number of worker processes
16 processes       = 3
17 # maximum number of threads to use
18 # threads
19 # the socket (use the full path to be safe
20 socket          = /home/user/mysite/mysite.sock
21 # ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
22 chmod-socket    = 666
23 #set the sockets listen queue size
24 #listen
25 # clear environment on exit
26 vacuum          = true
```

And here is how I restart my uwsgi

```
kill -SIGHUP [pid id of your uwsgi master]
```

Please note that the command you have provided for uwsgi using the ini file should only be used once to start the uwsgi server. When you want to restart, I suggest you note down the pid of the uwsgi master by using

```
 ps -ef | grep uwsgi
```

and run the above kill command.

Answer (score 0):

Venturing another possible cause for logging stopping after some time. uWSGI can be set to drop privileges (which is a good idea). However after this event `logto2` [0] setting is used:

```
logto=/var/www/app.com/logs/uwsgi/app.com-0.log
logto2=/var/www/app.com/logs/uwsgi/app.com-normaluser-0.log
```

Hope it helps someone.

[0] https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#logto2